# Cannot delete a file with special characters in filename (somehow hidden file)?

Tags: filesystems, cmd.exe, file-management

Running `dir /a` yields something like this:

```
05.06.2020  14:28            35.328 2020.06.05 - xy.doc
21.10.2021  10:44            14.111 2021.10.21 - xy.docx
29.11.2022  23:50    <DIR>          Dertttt
26.05.2013  08:59            23.040 _Briefkopf.doc
18.08.2008  14:10               162 ~$arbuch - Vollmacht xy, 18.08.2008.doc
```

I want to get rid of the file "~$arbuch - Vollmacht xy, 18.08.2008.doc".
Seems like an old Word backup file?
I cant see it in my explorer even when hidden files are configured to be shown.

If I run this from CMD:

`del "~$arbuch - Vollmacht xy, 18.08.2008.doc"`

it yields:

```
D:\MyFiles\Documents\~$arbuch - Vollmacht xy, 18.08.2008.doc could not be found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Depending on the attributes you'd also have to enable being able to see system files rather than just hidden files. You could give it a try with PowerShell and run `Get-ChildItem -Hidden -System` to make sure you're seeing it there as well. If you do run `Remove-Item '~$arbuch - Vollmacht xy, 18.08.2008.doc'`. The single quotes are important in that case.

Comment: Seems like we are on the right track. What I tried: Open Powershell as admin (via CMD+R -> Powershell -> Shift+Enter). In the title it says "Administrator: Windows PowerShell". Then I changed into the directory by using `cd .\myFolder`, when I enter `Remove-Item '~$` it autocompletes the filename, so Powershell definitely finds the file! But when I press enter, it says `Remove-Item : The item xy\~$arbuch - Vollmacht xy, 18.08.2008.doc cannot be removed: You
do not have sufficient access permissions to perform this operation.`

Comment: But though, you brought me on the right track. I had to enable showing hidden system files in the Explorer options - now I saw the file and could remove it easily via Windows Explorer. If you want, post your answer and I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides being a hidden file a file might also be marked as a system file. This should not be the case for but stuff happens. If it is a system file you also need to enable viewing system files, otherwise they will be hidden.

You can use PowerShell to cross check. Running ´Get-ChildItem -Hidden -System` should show the file and if it's flag contain H they're hidden if they contain an S they are marked as system files.

If a file shows up like that you can try to use `Remove-Item` to remove it. `Remove-Item` does support `-Force` as a parameter which can be helpful. If you do get a permission warning you could also try to run PowerShell with administrative privileges.

Keep in mind that with PowerShell it's important to use single quotes if you're handling strings with `$` as it typically denotes a variable. In your case `Remove-Item -Force '~$arbuch - Vollmacht xy, 18.08.2008.doc'` should've worked.